# openssl function to define cipher order

Tags: c++, c, ssl, encryption, openssl

I have a light http server (embedded software solution). This http server is calling openssl functions to handle https connexions.

I want to make the https server prioritize some ciphers. because according to the following [link](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-enabling-perfect-forward-secrecy.htm), the https connection is more secure when the DH cipher are prioritized:

> Instead of using the RSA method for exchanging session keys, you
>   should use the Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDHE) key exchange.
>   Note that you can still use the RSA public-key cryptosystem as the
>   encryption algorithm, just not as the key exchange algorithm. ECDHE is
>   much faster than ordinary DH (Diffie-Hellman), but both create session
>   keys that only the entities involved in the SSL connection can access.
>   Because the session keys are not linked to the server’s key pair, the
>   server’s private key alone cannot be used to decrypt any SSL session.
>
> To enable Perfect Forward Secrecy, you must do the following:
>
> 1- Reorder your cipher suites to place the ECDHE (Elliptic Curve
>   Diffie-Hellman) suites at the top of list, followed by the DHE
>   (Diffie-Hellman) suites.
>
> 2- Configure servers to enable other non-DH-key-exchange cipher
>   suites from the list of cipher suites offered by the SSL Client.

How I can change the cipher order on my openssl server to make the DH ciphers first?

Comment: Where's the code...

Comment: Dubious source material. SSL uses symmetric encryption, not PKI. If you don't use RSA for key exchange, you aren't using it at all.

Answer (score 2):

From the OpenSSL documentation, the relevant function call here is [`SSL_set_cipher_list`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_set_cipher_list.html)

The OpenSSL recommended string to use here is `HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4`, since the `!kRSA` disables using RSA as the key exchange and forces the use of ephemeral DH, which provides the Perfect Forward Secrecy that you describe in your question.

As a disclaimer, the cipher string above may not be what is recommended today, it is just what is recommended in the OpenSSL documentation.

Comment: is it possible to use the `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` instead of `SSL_set_cipher_list()` after ssl CTX init?